# Improve neo4j match when multiple types involved

Tags: neo4j, query-optimization

We have an usecase in neo4j that query matches for more than a type as below

```
MATCH (p)-[r]->(c) WHERE labels(p) in $parent_labels
```

This query very slow comparing when the type is given which makes sense because doesn't need to scan too many nodes. But my usecase would have more than a type. Is there anyway to improve the query performance

Comment: Is the parentlabel parameter dynamic? You could do where n:label1 or n:label2 or do an union

Comment: You should use the correct neo4j terminology, to avoid confusion. A **relationship** has 1 (and only 1) `type`. But a **node** can have 0 or more `labels`.

Comment: Also, presumably `parent` should be `p`. And the `LABELS(p) IN $parent_labels` predicate would test if the entire *list* of label names for `p` matches any of the strings in the `$parent_labels` list -- which will never be true.

Comment: @TomažBratanič, I've even tried this before. But the indexes are applied after it scans entire nodes in both types. Pls note that I tried with other conditions which are indexed property.

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings:
Nodes, that have **at least one** of given labels:

```
MATCH (p)-[r]->(c)
WHERE ALL (label IN labels(p) WHERE label IN $parent_labels)
```

Nodes, that have **all** given labels:

```
MATCH (p)-[r]->(c)
WHERE ALL (parent_label IN $parent_labels WHERE parent_label IN labels(p))
```